# GPU crash in release config only

Tags: linux, windows, crash, kernel, gpu

I have a host caller class with a callback to create a pointer to a class on the GPU. In this callback, a kernel is called to create the instance of the class on the GPU. I properly allocate memory on the GPU for this class pointer.

Next, a method on this class is called via a second kernel and the result is copied back to the host.

All this seems to work fine in debug mode but crashes in release mode. This occurs both in Windows and in Linux. This happens whether I compile the 2 .cu files as part of one executable or as a static (or dynamic) lib and an executable linking to the library.

Only way I can make it work in release mode is to not go through the caller class to execute the kernels but unfortunately, this does not work for my application. I would think that I am not doing anything wrong in terms of GPU memory management since it all works fine in debug mode.

I have come up with a simple example that replicates the problem and I am including the various pieces of code below. You can just compile both .cu files in Windows or Linux as part of a unique executable to replicate the issue.

Thank you very much in advance for your help and best regards.

- **function.cuh**

```
class function {

public:

    __device__ function() {}
    virtual __device__ ~function() {}

    virtual __device__ double calc(const double& x) const = 0;
};

class pointer_derived : public pointer_base
{
    function** m_p;

public:

    pointer_derived(function** p) : m_p(p) {}

    operator function** () { return m_p; }
};
```

- **StaticLib.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "Caller.h"

double run_function(Caller* f, const double& x, bool use_local);
```

- **StaticLib.cu**

```
#include "StaticLib.h"
#include "function.cuh"

class myfunction_local : public function {

public:

    __device__ myfunction_local() {}
    __device__ ~myfunction_local() {}

    __device__ double calc(const double& x) const
    {
        return x * x;
    }

};

__global__ void invoke_function(double* p, function** func, double x)
{
    *p = (*func)->calc(x);
}

__global__ void invoke_local_builder(function** ptr)
{
    *ptr = new myfunction_local();
}

double run_function(Caller* c, const double& x, bool use_local)
{
    function** func_p;

    cudaError_t cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&func_p, sizeof(function*));

    pointer_derived ptr(func_p);

    if (use_local)
        invoke_local_builder<<<1,1>>>(ptr);
    else
        c->get_function(ptr);

    double* p;

    cudaStatus = cudaMalloc(&p, sizeof(double));

    invoke_function<<<1,1>>>(p,func_p,x);

    double res;

    cudaMemcpy(&res, p, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    return res;
}
```

- **Caller.h**

```
#pragma once

class pointer_base {

public:

    pointer_base() {}
    virtual ~pointer_base() {}

};

class Caller {

public:

    Caller() {}
    ~Caller() {}

    void get_function(pointer_base& ptr);

};
```

- **Caller.cu**

```
#include "Caller.h"
#include "function.cuh"

class myfunction : public function {

public:

    __device__ myfunction() {}
    __device__ ~myfunction() {}

    __device__ double calc(const double& x) const
    {
        return x * x;
    }

};


__global__ void invoke_builder(function** ptr)
{
    *ptr = new myfunction();
}


void Caller::get_function(pointer_base& func_p)
{
    function** ptr = dynamic_cast<pointer_derived&>(func_p);
    invoke_builder<<<1,1>>>(ptr);

}

#include <iostream>
#include "StaticLib.h"

int main()
{
    Caller caller;

    // use_local = true - works both in release and config
    // use_local = false - crashes in release mode but works in debug mode

    bool use_local = true; 

    double res = run_function(&caller, 2.0, use_local);

    std::cout << res << std::endl;

}
```

I was expecting debug and release configuration to have the same behavior.